# Event handler on specific select value with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am wondering how to fire an event in jQuery based on a specific select value. So, for example i have a small select and div like so:

```
<select id="sweets">
  <option value ="Option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value ="Option2">Option 2</option>
  <option value ="Option3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<div id='showthis'>You have selected option 2</div>
```

I want to do something like;

if the user select Option 2,

```
$('#showthis').show();
```

if the user selects any other option,

```
$('#showthis').hide();
```

I am fairly new to jQuery and i'm not sure how to do a change event based on a specic select value.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#sweets').change(function(){
    var show = $(this).val() == 'Option2';
    $('#showthis').toggle(show);
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after, thank you very much. I knew it involved change(function)), but wasn't quite sure how to grab the specific value i needed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
$('#sweets').change(function() {
    if($(this).attr('value') == 'Option1') {
        // do something
    } else if($(this).attr('value') == 'Option2') {
        // do something else
    } // etc..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#sweets').change(function() {
    if( this.selectedIndex === 1 ) {
         $('#showthis').show();
    } else {
         $('#showthis').hide();
    }
});
```

or better yet:

```
$('#sweets').change(function() {
    $('#showthis').toggle( this.selectedIndex === 1 );
});
```

The `selectedIndex` property is a very fast way to reference the selected option.

Using the [`toggle()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method you can pass a boolean as a *switch* argument where `true == show` and `false == hide`.

Or to do it by value, you could do this:

```
$('#sweets').change(function() {
    var val = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value;
    $('#showthis').toggle( val === 'Option1' );
});
```